# Get Name of XML Column

Tags: xml, web-services, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an XML that looks like this:

```xml
<data name='dat1'>
  <row name='row1'>
    <orange>blah</orange>
    <red>more blah</red>
  </row>
</data>
```

I am passing this XML through an HTTP post. On the destination ASP page I want to detect the names of the columns within `<row></row>`. I currently can use this to get the value of a column where I know the column name:

```vb
Set dataRowList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row")
Dim datarow
For Each datarow In dataRowList
    name = datarow.GetAttribute("name")
    If InStr(1, name, "row") > 0 Then
        Dim param1 : param1 = datarow.SelectSingleNode("orange").Text
    End If
Next
```

The result is the value of column "orange". But I would like my code to figure out the column names dynamically based on the XML being requested. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Use an [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expression for selecting the `<row>` nodes, then enumerate the child nodes of those nodes. The names of the child nodes can be obtained via their `NodeName` property.

```vb
For Each row In xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//row[contains(@name, 'row')]")
    For Each col In row.ChildNodes
        WScript.Echo col.NodeName
    Next
Next
```